# Trying to make a program where I roll 1 die 6 mil times while counting the amount of times it landed on each side. then displaying it decimal form

Tags: java

```
public class dice1 {
    public static final int N = 6000000;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] d = new int[7];
        for (int i = 1; i < 7; i++) d[i] = 0;
            for (int k = 0; k < N; k++) {
                int roll = (int)(6 * Math.random() + 1);
                d[roll]++;
            }
            System.out.println("Rolls: " + N);

            for (int i = 1; i < 7; i++) {
                float decimal = d[i] / N;
                System.out.print(" " + i + ": " + d[i]);
                System.out.printf( ", " + i + " was rolled %f" , decimal);
                System.out.println();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My problem is I have to display it in decimal form. For example on the side with 6 dots it could be 1 mil times out of 6 mil so the output should be like ".16". Mine ends up 0.00. Any tips?

Comment: Both `N` is an `int` an `d[]` is an `int[]` so decimal fractions will be dropped.  So cast `d[i]` to `float` before dividing.  `(float)d[i]/N`.  That way you will not be doing integer math.  And I usually use `double` not `float`  Or just declare d[] as a floating point array (either float or double).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since both `d[i]` and `N` are `int`s, you're performing [integer division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_(mathematics)#Of_integers), which only retains the "whole" part, left of the decimal point. Since `d[i]` is smaller than `N`, you're getting `0`.

You could solve this by casting one of them to a floating point type, e.g.:

```
float decimal = ((float) d[i]) / N;
```

Or just define them like that to beging with.